# How to Raise Click Event Of Button in Code Behind in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I Am working on WPF Application and I want to raise click event of Button that i created for Button Earlier on Run time. And i Want Button click should be dynamic 
For Example: I have two Button one is City1 and One is State1 and Both have Click Event again i have another Button with same name City2 and State2. What i want is I want to raise Event of City1 click and as well State1 Click 
Here is My Code:

```
Button getSpecificButton = XYZ.Common.ExtensionMethods.FindLogicalChildren<Button>(this).Where(btn1 => btn1.Content == Intrbt.Content).FirstOrDefault();
if (getSpecificButton != null && getSpecificButton.Content != null)
{
    //getSpecificButton.Name = getSpecificButton.Content.ToString();
    //getSpecificButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
}
```

i Have this Extension Method which is used get all the button in application Here i am gettting Exception.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindLogicalChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            foreach (object rawChild in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(depObj))
            {
                if (rawChild is DependencyObject)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = (DependencyObject)rawChild;
                    if (child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindLogicalChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this code is not Working Please Try to solve this issue.

Comment: I'd suggest to use an `ICommand` implementation to bind a `Button.Command` property. Then you do not need to walk through the visual tree and simulate a click on the button but you just execute the `ICommand` in code behind without the need to even access the visual tree.

Comment: I can not use ICommand Because there are 100 buttons i have to change complete code . So please provide a solution

Comment: State1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent)); While Writing a particular name of the button its working fine. but if i am assiging a button as getSpecificButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent)); throwing Exception.

Comment: What exception? NullReferenceException? :)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Comment: Which line of code causes this exception? Please describe your problem better so we can to help you faster.

Comment: Actually i created one extension method for getting all button in application there i am getting error. I am trying to paste extension method here but i crossed the number of char here so complete method can not come propery

Comment: Create separate question for problem with `FindLogicalChildren`. Current question addresses issue with raising of Click event. But traversing of logical or visual tree is a simple task. You can find a lot of examples on the Internet.

Comment: Please Check update Question Of Mine.

Comment: Thank you everyone . I find solution my self.

Answer (score -1):

```
getSpecificButton.Click += btn_Click;

//separate method
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

This will work. 
But please use ICommand as commented by Adwaenyth.

Comment: This will not work for me actually. because i don't know the button click on run time whatever button is coming should call their related raise click event. For Example If State clicked then state_click should raise, If City Click then city_click  should  raise but in same method i can achieve this through if else or switch but i have 100 buttons and  i want to avoid 100 switch or if block that's why i am asking